# How to use selfPermit with Multicall?

Tags: solidity, web3js, uniswap

Modern AMM routers (eg UniswapV3, Trident) feature an abstract contract `selfPermit.sol` that allow users to submit their own ERC712 permit signature and call another contract function in a single transaction.

As per [Uniswap documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/base/SelfPermit), "*These functions are expected to be embedded in multicalls to allow EOAs to approve a contract and call a function that requires an approval in a single transaction.*".

I cannot find any web3 reference implementation of how this work though. How to use Multicall to selfPermit + do action (eg swap) in a single transaction?

note: ERC712 signature process is clear, the question is focused on selfPermit w/ Multicall

Looking for a web3.js illustrative implementation.